# Объясните многопоточную архитектуру работы процессора и защиты памяти

Tags: linux, многопоточность, ос, процессор, микроархитектура

Интересует как взаимодействуют несколько процессов и ОС.

Правильно ли я понимаю что в момент запуска компьютера запускается ОС и т.к. запустилась первая получается возможность записать в некоторый регистр то что она является самым главным процессом и уровень защиты 0.

ОС же по сути является таким же процессом ?

Далее допустим мы в системе запустили несколько программ, и допустим что у нас однопроцессорный компьютер. Процессы выполняются фактически по очереди и ставятся на "паузу" после нескольких тактов как я понимаю.

Т.е. в некой таблице хранится номер процесса и какая то информация о нем, в т.ч. на какой строчке остановлено выполнение, а так же номер защиты для процессора.

Когда код возвращается к выполнению определенного процесса он переводит процессор в режим соответствующий защите текущего процесса? А когда код возвращается к работе самой ОС то соответственно ставится 0 ?

А когда процесс вызывает системный вызов ОС то получается переключается в режим защиты 0? Или создается новый подпроцесс от имени ОС который выполняет что-то и возвращает процессу?

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Надеюсь кто-то даст хороший ответ. Только сегодня читал как [это работает](https://habr.com/ru/post/423049/). ОС - это определение включает довольно много. В контексте вопроса бОльшая часть относится к ядру ОС (Linux kernel). Ядро делает очень много "мелкой работы" - управлением памятью, распределение квантов времени между процессами, и т.п.  `на какой строчке остановлено выполнение` - нет понятия строчки. Есть [регистр процессора IP](http://www.sbup.com/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)

Comment: "на какой строчке" я имел ввиду в коде программы какой либо запушенной как процесс.

Comment: Вопрос очень глобальный. На него нельзя ответить, если не уточнять ОС. А если уточнять, то ответ - это пара-тройка книг.

Comment: @KoVadim в тегах написано Linux. Конкретный дистр не указан, но там все работает более-менее одинаково в контексте вопроса, потому что эти операции на уровне ядра.  ПавелКозлов, там действительно есть таблица, какой процесс, на каком месте остановился - посмотрите по ссылке в моем первом сообщении

Comment: @TotalPusher да интересует в первую очередь именно linux. Но даже не конкретная реализация, я просто хочу представить концептуально как это работает на уровень железа. Т.е. у меня есть бесконечный цикл процессора который всегда "ищет" что сделать, когда запушена ОС он выполняет ее какие то операции, когда запускаются еще какие то процессы (представим просто программы на С++ считающие факториал) процессор чередует выполнение этих процессов и в т.ч. работу самой ОС, так? т.е. ОС как отдельный процесс для процессора по сути? Не совсем понятно что происходит при вызове из кода системных вызовов ОС

Comment: И плюс не совсем все таки понимаю как происходит защита данных на уровен процессора

Comment: У вас очень много вопросов в одном. Вам бы стоило серьезно почитать книги по архитектуре процессора, что бы понимать что делает он, а что ОС. Например "Григорьев в.л. микропроцессор i486. архитектура и программирование" (при некотором желании можно найти в электронном виде бесплатно). По переключению задач в Linux https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941246/